# Nodejs npm install karma

Tags: node.js, karma-runner

When I installed karma in nodejs modules, in my log written this:

```
npm http 304 https registry.npmjs.org/proto-list

> phantomjs@1.9.1-5 install C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma-phantomjs-launcher\node_modules\phantomjs
> node install.js

Downloading http://phantomjs.googlecode.com/files/phantomjs-1.9.1-windows.zip
Saving to \tmp\phantomjs\phantomjs-1.9.1-windows.zip
Receiving...

C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma-phantomjs-launcher\node_modules\phantomjs\install.js:215
  deferred.reject('Error with http request: ' + util.inspect(response.head
                                                ^
ReferenceError: util is not defined
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma-phantomjs-launcher\node_modules\phantomjs\install.js:215:53)
at ClientRequest.g (events.js:175:14)
at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (http.js:1669:21)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:120:23)
at Socket.socketOnData [as ondata] (http.js:1564:20)
at TCP.onread (net.js:525:27)
npm ERR! weird error 8
npm ERR! not ok code 0

d:\nodejs>npm install util

npm http 304 https registry.npmjs.org/events.node
util@0.4.9 node_modules\util
└── events.node@0.4.9
```

module util already installed.
Why karma not installing?

Comment: Try this `npm install -g karma`

Comment: Yes, this was my first command )

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error (on Linux though). The thing is this:

PhantomJS comes with it's own "installer" [`install.js`](https://github.com/Obvious/phantomjs/blob/04b36ddd139bd67f704ea9f738e7300a9fb4d7dd/install.js#L139) that is fetching the precompiled PhantomJS binaries to a temporary directory and unzips them to somewhere inside your `node_modules` directory.

I had to export the `TMPDIR` variable because `/tmp` was not writable. In your case it looks like the `\tmp` fallback doesn't cut it (it's Windows after all).
Try setting `TMPDIR` to point to an existing directory and run `npm install` again.

Good luck!

PS: Can anyone extend this answer with instructions on how to set environment variables on Windows?

Comment: I set the value of the variable `TMPDIR`, but the same error appeared again.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded fantomjs zip, and replaced it in `TMPDIR`.
After that, again launched installing karma.
And this happened.
But when I launched nodejs from tutorial script, I took error...
But that other story...

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me-

The phantomJSZip is downloaded (at least it tries to) in

```
C:\tmp\phantomjs
```

But the file size is 0kb. So I downloaded one from PhantomJS website and copied to that location.

All credit goes to the two answers before me. I just did a search for the zip file.